# How to create animation on progress bar like in capitalistGame?

Tags: android, animation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBUK0.png)

I want to make animation on progressbar like in capitalist game in android using code.Can you help me?Do you have any ideas how to complete it in best way?

Comment: Can you show gif animated this progress?

Comment: here is a link https://tenor.com/view/windows-progressbar-progress-bar-gif-5424985
I need to create animation like that